# a table with same name as user system table in postgresl

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I have a table in my database named the same as the system table "user"  I cannot figure out how to set the environment so that I select from my "user" table and not the system table as the postgres user.   I have tried

```
SET SCHEMA 'myschema';
```

and also at the psql connection line

```
PGOPTIONS=--search_path=myschema psql -U postgres -d mydatabase
```

but these have not worked.  I still have to prefix my table as

`myschema.user` when I execute sql commands in psql.

Is there a way to set the environment so that it will default to my "user" table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no system table called "user". "user" is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and a [system information function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) on top of this.

All reserved words could be used for identifiers, but have to be [quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: it seems then that I am stuck with two choices.  use myschema.user or change the name of my table in this case.  Is that correct?

Comment: Or you could include the `myschema` in the `search_path` and then refer to your table with its quoted name, e.g. `select ... from "user"`.